# Login accepts blank character in password Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am having very strange but serious issue with Joomla 3 log in form. When I entered the wrong credentials it's working fine, even if I put space between password, it's working fine and gave an error. But if I put space(can add any no of space) before or after with the correct password it get accepted and I can logged in to system, which should not happened. It should give an error. I am searching for it from last 6-8 hour but didn't find any thread about. hope some one has any suggestion about that.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot create a user with a password that starts or ends with a space character.

Thus a trim operation can be done (it is certainly done) before the validation of the password.

It certainly exists :

- to remove some problem with copy/paste from user
- or to be compatible with some hash functions used in Joomla ?

Comment: Didn't get what you want to suggest, even it's not related to what i have asked.

Comment: I think I have explained why blank characters are accepted at the beginning and at the end of the password field. Elin says as me it is to remove some problem with copy/paste from user input. But maybe I haven't understood your question/problem...? I don't suggest anything, I just explain why you have this behavior in Joomla which seems normal.